# Jenkinsfile - calling multiple groovy scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy

We have our shared libraries on gitlab called `mainlibrary` and it has a lot of groovy files.

Example in mainlibrary gitlab repo we have the following files.

```
startup_pipeline.groovy
cleanup_pipeline.groovy
```

In one of our Jenkins job we need to include multiple groovy files in the `Jenkinsfile`. Is this possible?

This is how the `Jenkinsfile` looks like:

```
@Library('mainlibrary')_
startup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com')
```

Can I include the second groovy function file into this `Jenkinsfile` like this?

```
@Library('mainlibrary')_
startup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com'),
cleanup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com')
```

Comment: If you have set the gitlab repo as shared library you should be able to call every file that is in that repo so yes, you should be able to call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the `cleanup_pipeline.groovy` is located under the `vars` folder and your code already has a complete declaration inside, your example may work, and the second file can be included. The only modification is the extra comma:

```
@Library('mainlibrary')_
startup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com')
cleanup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com')
```

Or can be under `src` and imported, but I never used this approach.
Usually, I keep the main logic inside `vars`, and other complex things go to `src`.

Based on Jenkins [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), see more in *Directory structure* and *Defining custom steps*.

Video [step by step building a shared library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wj-weFEsTb0), you can build and test something similar if you are not sure about the structure.